# Can't connect to RDS through EC2

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rds

I'm trying to access an RDS instance from an EC2 instance but with no luck. I'm able to connect to RDS from pgAdmin without any problem, but I'm try to connect to it from EC2 using psql I get the following error:

```
psql: could not translate host name "pgrds.cqvae2m3k8q9.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com" to address: Name or service not known
```

I have both instances running in the same VPC and using the same security group, which have all traffic open both ways. I've spent quite some time on this, and tried several solutions but none worked.

Comment: Have you tried to `dig pgrds.cqvae2m3k8q9.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com` from the instance where you're having a problem? Can you telnet to the box with `telnet pgrds.cqvae2m3k8q9.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com 5432` from the box with the problem?

Comment: Do the hostnames in pgAdmin config match what you use from CLI? Is that host ping-able?

Comment: I see it resolves fine: https://goo.gl/mTNCfW. As other people have mentioned, see if you can dig this host or any other host from your EC2 instance. This name is CNAME-d to ec2-52-26-99-1.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com (52.26.99.1), see if this works.

Comment: You can also try `dig @ns pgrds.cqvae2m3k8q9.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com` taking "ns" from this list: https://goo.gl/ikjbsb

Comment: One thing I end up doing was to use the actual RDS ip instead of the regular endpoint. I'm not sure why this worked, but well... it did! Would this be an acceptable answer?